# Camponotus queen ant eggs turning brown

Tags: insects

My camponotus queens eggs are turning brown. Does anyone know why, or if it is good or bad, and if it is bad how do I fix it? Her eggs have been brown for some time.

A Camponotus is a [Carpenter ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpenter_ant)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Pets.se  if possible can you expand how long "some time" is, weeks, days, hours?  Also include a picture if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing photos I suspect the reason they're turning brown is the eggs which start start out very small and white have progressed to the pupa stage and what you are seeing are cocoons rather than eggs. The following article from the [University of Florida](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/ants/fl_carpenter_ants.htm) is worth a read and a photo from that page shows some of the life-cycle of a Camponotus  / Carpenter ant:

[image: Florida Carpenter ant]

Although the color reproduction doesn't appear ideal in that photo if you do an image search on "carpenter ant pupae" you'll see a lot of images that depict a brown color. If that's the case it's nothing to worry about and I'd guess in a month or two they should emerge from the cocoon given a few references I found said they normally progress from egg to adult in 6-12 weeks.

Comment: Nope they are still small little egg dots. She ate the brown eggs so I let her go. I have another queen though.